# Jquery Clear / reset .Queue()?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that triggers two functions whenever a button is clicked. However it only fires the functions once. If i click it again, it does nothing. I need to reset this queue so it fires the functions everytime I click the button.

Also, I'm only doing this so I can delay the functions from be fired 1000ms - is there another way to do this?

```
$('#play').click(function() { 
// other code..

$(this).delay(1000).queue(function(){ countHourly(); countFlights() });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> jQuery.delay() is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects and such, and is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases. http://api.jquery.com/delay/

I suggest you use the setTimeout function in this case

```
$('#play').click(function() { 
  setTimeout(function(){ countHourly(); countFlights() }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Set a timer to delay execution of
>   *subsequent* items in the queue.
>   [**.delay()**](http://api.jquery.com/delay)

```
$(this).delay(1000).queue(function(){ countHourly(); countFlights() });// delay 1000 would just happen if $(this) is being animated before .delay(1000)...
```

I would suggest you use `window.setTimeout()`